# Explain line "s = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol)"

Tags: sockets

```
int s;
struct addrinfo hints, *res;

getaddrinfo("www.example.com", "http", &hints, &res);

s = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
```

Please explain the last line of code

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add tags for the language and frameworks/libraries you used.

Comment: @prog-fh Why everyone writes the answers in the comments?

Comment: @prog-fh An answer must not be detailed to be posted as an answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296481/420538

Comment: @ominug Ah OK, I didn't realise it was a problem, and I was just mimicking what I see very often here. I delete all of these comments right now. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @prog-fh, sure delete, but copy paste the answer into an actual answer! XD

Comment: @ominug Reformulated in a (quite more detailed) answer below; thanks for your advice.

Comment: @WurmD Reformulated in a (quite more detailed) answer below; thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

The notion of *socket* is a very generic communication means.
It could deal with communication between local processes, communication between your process and some internal aspects of your system's kernel (events...), communication through the network...
Even when it deals with the network, there exists many protocol families and many protocols.

That's why, when we create a socket (with the `socket()` call on your last line), we have to provide several parameters in order to select the right properties of the required socket.
[man 2 socket](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) mainly explains the first parameter (*domain* or *protocol family*) but the other parameters are explained in subsequent pages since they depend on the choice made with this first parameter.

Note that once a socket is obtained with the `socket()` call, you may need to provide many other settings by other system calls, depending on your intention (`bind()` for a server, `connect()` for a client... many settings exist).

In your example, it seems that you want to reach an HTTP server named `www.example.com`.
You could have *hardcoded* the fact that such a server can be reached with the `AF_INET` protocol family (for ipv4, or `AF_INET6` for ipv6), through a TCP connection (type `SOCK_STREAM`, protocol `0`) but the [`getaddrinfo()` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) can help provide all these details and some other to be used in subsequent system calls (IP address and port number to be specified in a subsequent `connect()` call for example).
All this information stands in the members of the returned `struct addrinfo`.